# How to get heap memory usage, FreeRTOS

Tags: c, heap-memory, freertos

In a FreeRTOS environment, how can I get the amount of heap used at runtime by all the tasks?

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: For future reference, I found the duplicate by searching `[freertos] heap`. Putting the tag name in square brackets limits the search to questions with that tag.

Comment: @tadman, the documentation says nothing of how to get the amount of heap used at runtime

Comment: Search xPortGetFreeHeapSize() and xPortGetMinimumEverHeapSize() on https://www.freertos.org/a00111.html

Comment: I am quite agree with @Richard and you can define MAX Heap size   configAPPLICATION_ALLOCATED_HEAP  in FreeRTOSConfig.h,